# How to write a python program that finds the first n numbers that are not divisible by any other prime number except 2, 3, and 5

Tags: python, function, primes

I need to create a program that takes user input n and the finds the first n numbers that aren't divisible by any other prime numbers except 2, 3, and 5. This is what I've got so far:

```
def is_divisible(i):
    for k in range(7, i):
        if is_prime(k) == 1 and i % k == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0


def is_prime(k):
    for j in range(2, k):
        if k % j == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1


while True:
    while True:
        while True:
            try:
                n = input("How many numbers do you want to find: ")
                n = n.replace(" ", "")
                n = int(n)
                break
            except:
                print("Input only natural numbers")
                continue

        if n == 0:
            print("Input only natural numbers")
            continue
        else:
            break

    count = 0
    i = 0
    while count < n:
        if i % 2 == 0 and i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0 and is_divisible(i) == 0:
            print(i)
            count += 1
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1

    repeat = input("To repeat press (1), to end press anything else: ")
    if str(repeat) == "1":
        continue
    else:
        print("Bye!")
        break
```

If asked to find 10 numbers the program outputs:

```
30
60
90
120
150
180
240
270
300
330
```

The program didn't print 210 (which is divisible by 7) so the algorithm seems, at least, partly correct, but 330 is printed (which is divisible by 11) and I can't figure out why. If I manually change i to 330 and k to 11, the is_prime function correctly finds that 11 is a prime number, but the is_divisible function still returns 0. I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: General advice: Use `True` and `False` for boolean values, not `1` and `0`.

Comment: Those are ugly numbers.

Comment: I haven't seen the programming assignment, but I'm guessing that the answers should start this way: 2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,.... that is, numbers that are ONLY divisible by 2,3 AND/OR 5.   If you need to find numbers that are divisible y 2,3,and5, you are essentially looking for mulitples of 30.  Which will be the essentially the list I gave you already * 30  (plus we would add 30 to the beginning).

Comment: As @Barmar indicated, your is_prime() function is wrong.  For instance, `is_prime(9)` returns 1 simply because it is not divisible by 2.

Comment: @Mark Unlikely that they want multiples of 30, this is a somewhat well-known problem, see [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ugly+numbers) or [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A051037) or [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number).

Comment: @Kelly probably not, since their complaint about the output was that it included 330, not that it _didn't_ include 1, 2, 3, 4, etc (unless OP has misunderstood their assignment and come up with the wrong expected output in the first place). OP, please clarify.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, I think they either didn't realize that they have false negatives, or they're simply asking about their false positives first.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of code that looks for values that have other factors besides 2,3,5.  If there are other factors in there, they must be other prime values because we remove the prime factors 2,3,5 from the number.

```
primes = [ 2, 3, 5] 

count = 10

answers = []
value = 2
while len(answers) < count:
  
  test_value = value
  for prime in primes:
    while test_value % prime == 0:
      test_value //= prime

  if test_value == 1:
    answers.append(value)

  value += 1

print(answers)
```

Ok, the performance discussion from @Kelly Bundy bothered me - so I added a different approach - but it's got problems.

```
import sys
primes = [ 2, 3, 5] 

count = int(sys.argv[1])


base =  round( count ** (1./3.) ) 

powers = [0] * len(primes)

answers = []
while True:
  value = 1
  for n in range(len(primes)):
    value *= primes[n] ** powers[n] 

  answers.append(value)
  for n in range(len(powers)):
    powers[n] += 1
    if powers[n] != base:
      break
    powers[n] = 0
  else:
    break

  
for x in sorted(answers):
  print(x)
```

Basically, all of the numbers we want to find are of the form:  `2**x * 3**y *  5**z` .  And so, if we just vary x,y,and z, we can compute all of the qualifying numbers.

The the problem boils down to, which values of x,y, and z are valid.  To be honest, I haven't figured that out.  All I do is come up with `count` combinations of x,y,z where I just count values (using some base counting system).  For instance, if I need to come up with 1,000 combinations, I just produce all of the combinations of x,y,z where the values are between 0 and 9.  And so  i get the values (000 - 999).  And this produces the values: `2**0 * 3**0 * 5**0` all the way up to `2**9 * 3**9 * 5**9`.   Now, I'm definitely missing some values.  The 1,000 numbers I come up with are NOT the first 1,000 numbers.

Comment: Assuming @KellyBundy you were referring to the `/=` I've modified that to `//=`.  Thanks for the edit!

Comment: If you would like get answers as multiples of 30 (that is, values that must have 2,3, and 5 as factors) you can change the line `answers.append(value)` to `answer.append(value * 30)`.   If you want to include 30 as the first item in the list, start with `value = 1`

Comment: Yes, I meant the `/=`. Granted, with your method you likely won't reach the problematic larger numbers because it's so slow, but it's still better to just use ints.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the above algorithm is so slow.  I am guessing it's O( n log n ).   The determination that any value is only divisible by 2,3,5 only takes  at most 3 * log(n) operations.    Nonetheless, I have a suspicion that you are right in that it is not optimal.

Comment: I don't think it's n log n. Might be exponential. The 10000th number is 288325195312500000 and I can find the first 10000 numbers in a split second. I don't think your code can.

Comment: You are right.  I found the 1,000th number in 35 seconds.  On the other hand, it's simple :).

Comment: Yeah, mine is a bit tricky, although that's because this time I challenged myself to completely avoid Python in the computation (i.e., I just plugged some itertools etc together). I've written simple efficient versions before.

Comment: Sorry to bother :-). And yes, building the numbers by multiplying is what I do as well (just differently).

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to fix your `is_prime` like [@Barmar mentions above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74227007/how-to-write-a-python-program-that-finds-the-first-n-numbers-that-are-not-divisi#comment131049919_74227007)

Note, this can be optimized in multiple ways, the simplest of which is to only check `for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(k))+1)` because a number `k` won't have any prime factors greater than `sqrt(k)`. Also, we can memorize all the prime numbers found so far, so that if the same number is checked multiple times, subsequent checks are much faster. You can use better algorithms to check if a number is prime, but this should suffice for our purposes.

```
import math

# A set to remember prime numbers
primes = set()

def is_prime(k):

    if k == 1: return False       # 1 is not prime
    if k in primes: return True   # Check remembered prime numbers    

    # Check all numbers in the closed interval [2, sqrt(k)]
    for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(k))+1):
        if k % j == 0:
            return False
    
    # Prime number, so remember it
    primes.add(k)
    return True
```

---

> The first `n` numbers that aren't divisible by any prime numbers other than 2, 3, and 5

Since your number needs to be divisible by 2, 3, *and* 5, you don't need to look at *all* numbers as you do currently. Just look at multiples of `2 * 3 * 5`, i.e. multiples of `30`, since those are the only numbers that are going to be multiples of 2, 3, and 5.

So now your problem becomes: "Print `30 * i`, where `i` is *not* a multiple of a prime number other than `2`, `3`, and `5`. i.e., you need to get the *prime factors* of `i`, and check that this set contains only `2`, `3`, and `5`.

There are a number of ways to get the prime factors of a number. Here's a simple one:

```
def prime_factors(k):
    # If k is prime, it is its only prime factor
    if is_prime(k): 
        return {k}

    factors = set()

    # If divisible by 2, add 2 as a prime factor
    if k % 2 == 0: 
        factors.add(2)    

    # Check all odd numbers in the closed interval [3, k//2]
    for i in range(3, k//2+1, 2):
        if k % i == 0 and is_prime(i):
            factors.add(i)

    return factors
```

Now that we've defined our helper functions, we just need to call them:

```
n = 10

i = 1
count = 0
while count < n:
    factors = prime_factors(i)
    # If we remove {2, 3, 5} from factors, do we get an empty set?
    if not factors.difference({2, 3, 5}):
        print(2 * 3 * 5 * i)
        count += 1
    i += 1
```

Which prints:

```
30
60
90
120
150
180
240
270
300
360
```

---

If you are indeed looking for [regular numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number) as [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74227007/how-to-write-a-python-program-that-finds-the-first-n-numbers-that-are-not-divisi/74227468#comment131050019_74227007) and [@Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74227007/how-to-write-a-python-program-that-finds-the-first-n-numbers-that-are-not-divisi/74227468#comment131050640_74227007) suggest in their comments, then you simply skip the multiplication by `2 * 3 * 5`:

```
n = 10

i = 1
count = 0
while count < n:
    factors = prime_factors(i)
    # If we remove {2, 3, 5} from factors, do we get an empty set?
    if not factors.difference({2, 3, 5}):
        print(i)
        count += 1
    i += 1
```

gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
10
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `is_divisible` method basically only checks `7` and then returns either 1 or 0.
You want to check all the numbers in the range.

```
def is_divisible(i):
    for k in range(7, i):
        if is_prime(k) == 1 and i % k == 0:
            return 1
    return 0
```

Your `is_prime` method suffers from this issue as well:

```
def is_prime(k):
    for j in range(2, k):
        if k % j == 0:
            return 0
    return 1
```

Fixing these issues, however, is going make this algorithm EXTREMELY slow so you will need to consider some strategies that will make it faster.
Caching the numbers that you have already checked for primeness would be a start.